# Count of duplicates of a list in Pandas Dataframe by group

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a Dataframe that currently looks like this:

```
image         source                               label
bookshelf     A                      [flora, jar, plant]
bookshelf     B                    [indoor, shelf, wall]
bookshelf     C             [furniture, shelf, shelving]
cactus        A                     [flora, plant, vine]
cactus        B                [building, outdoor, tree]
cactus        C                  [home, house, property]
cars          A          [parking, parking lot, vehicle]
cars          B                     [car, outdoor, tree]
cars          C            [car, motor vehicle, vehicle]
```

What I would like to get is the count of duplicate `label`s for each `source` per `image`, i.e.:

1. for the `image` *bookshelf*, sources *B* and *C* share the "shelf" label (B+=1; C+=1)
2. for the `image` *cactus*, no sources share the same labels
3. for the `image` *cars*, sources *B* and *C* share the label "car" (B+=1; C+=1) and sources *A* and *C* share the label "vehicle" (A+=1; C+=1)

The response object would be the number of times sources share labels. In the example above, (1) would increase the *B* and *C* counts by 1 each, and (3) would increase the *B* and *C* counts by 1 each and the *A* and *C* counts by 1 each:

```py
{ 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3 }
```

**Reproducible example:**

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({
  'image': ['bookshelf', 'bookshelf', 'bookshelf',
            'cactus', 'cactus', 'cactus',
            'cars', 'cars', 'cars'],
  'source': ['A', 'B', 'C',
             'A', 'B', 'C',
             'A', 'B', 'C'],
  'label': [
    ['flora', 'jar', 'plant'],
    ['indoor', 'shelf', 'wall'],
    ['furniture', 'shelf', 'shelving'],
    ['flora', 'plant', 'vine'],
    ['building', 'outdoor', 'tree'],
    ['home', 'house', 'property'],
    ['parking', 'parking lot', 'vehicle'],
    ['car', 'outdoor', 'tree'],
    ['car', 'motor vehicle', 'vehicle']]
  },
  columns = ['image', 'source', 'label']
)
```

**While there are usually 3 labels per source/image, this isn't guaranteed.**

Any ideas on how I could achieve this with good performance? I have a few million records to process like it...

Comment: How is `label` represented? Strings? Lists?

Comment: `label` is a list of strings

Comment: Could you add the code to generate the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
from collections import Counter
sources = df['source'].unique()
output = {source: 0 for source in sources}
for image, sub_df in df.groupby('image'):
    counts = Counter(sub_df['label'].sum())
    for image, source, labels in sub_df.itertuples(index=False):
        for label in labels:
            output[source] += counts[label] - 1
print(output)
```

Comment: Terse and nice display of `Counter` and `itertuples`